# Automatically close database in sqlite3 of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, contextmanager

In Python sqlite3, the context manager

```
with sqlite3.connect(database)
```

would automatically commit or rollback transactions. However, it does not close the connection nor the cursor. So every time I have to write something like this:

```
with sqlite3.connect(database) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(an_sql_statement)
    cur.executemany(more_sql_statements)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

which becomes quite repetitive.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
with AutoCloseDB(database) as cur:
    cur.execute(an_sql_statement)
    cur.executemany(more_sql_statements)
```

and the above context manager would automatically commit or rollback transactions, close the cursor and finally close the database altogether upon exiting.

So I came up with the following context manager:

```
import sqlite3

class AutoCloseDB:
    """A context manager that automatically closes the cursor and the database.
    Return a cursor object upon entering.
    """

    def __init__(self, database):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(database)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = self.conn.__enter__()
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        return self.cur

    def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
        result = self.conn.__exit__(*exc_info)
        self.cur.close()
        self.conn.close()
        return result
```

Is there any problem in the above code? Is there any better solution?

Comment: Pardon the question - but why do you want to close the connection and the cursor?

Comment: I thought we should always explicitly close handles to resourses (e.g. files, webdriver, database, etc) when we are done? I may be wrong about this since I'm still a beginner in database.

Comment: The question is - you said you’re repeating this code in your app. As a general statement, opening database connections is considered an expensive operation, and you should refrain from too much open / close. That’s why people use connection pools - and in general don’t even manage connections directly.

Comment: In our case we are storing stock trading data in local computers. We pull the trading data from the broker's api once or twice a day (we don't do day trading). Then we do some stock analysis on the data at the end of each trading day. So we don't need to maintain the database connection all the time.